# Emulating file system traces by a c program

Tags: c, process, filesystems

I have a file with records of the type "PID, time of call, system call" and calls made by different processes are interleaved. Now, I am writing a simulator to replay the system calls and need a call made by say PID 1 to be made by a different process from a call made by say PID 2. Moreover the same process must make all the calls made by PID 1 and in the same order as appears in the trace file. Would be gratefull for some help. Thank you...

Comment: We're not here to write the code for you, of course, but if I were in your position I would start by writing a main() function, fleshing it out, and going from there.

Comment: @Bill I understand that no one is going to write the code for me and I am not expecting that. The logic here is not as simple as it looks. Main() reads the file trace file...checks the PID of a trace and makes a thread replay that trace..control comes back to main()...main() reads the trace file again and if it the same PID as before, the same thread is suppose to make that call but it exists no more.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to make a linked list with one PID member. For each call you could traverse the list (and add a node if the PID is not found) and make each node hold a filehandle or something where you can feed the process with data.
If yor PID's are not "random" numbers but 1,2,3,4 etc... you can always do the same thing with an array (of pointers) to avoid the time it takes to traverse the list.
Not sure if this is enough for you but again you don't really give much details...

Comment: Thank You. Will get back once I try